# add item into List<string> from another class in c#

Tags: c#, list, class

I have 3 class. Those are places.cs, onePlace.cs and placestovisit.cs.
placestovisit.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Sunamganj.ViewModels
{
    public class placestovisit
    {
        public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }
        public onePlace sunamganj { get; set; }
        public static string basePlaces = "Assets/Places/";
        private string baseTanguar = basePlaces + "Tanguar/";
        private string baseBaruni = basePlaces + "Baruni/";

        public void LoadData()
        {
            sunamganj = createSunamganj();

            IsDataLoaded = true;
        }

        private onePlace createSunamganj()
        {
            onePlace data = new onePlace();

            data.Items.Add(new places()
            {
                ID = "0",
                Title = "Tanguar Haor",
                shortDescription="Tanguar Haor (Lowlaying marsh) is a complex landscape of over 46 marshes, 30 km Northwest of Sunamgonj District.",
                itemImage = baseTanguar + "1.jpg",

                FullDescription = "Tanguar Haor (Lowlaying marsh) is a complex landscape of over 46 marshes, 30 km Northwest of Sunamgonj District. The marshes are inter connected with one another through narrow Channels but merge into a single large water body during monsoon. The aquatic vegetation and less disturbance from the human are instrument to invite a large variety of waterfowl specially winter migrant ducks that congregates in thousands. Resident and local migrant, raptor, waders and passerine birds made the area as one of the Asia's most potential birding place. Tanguar Haor is listed as a Ramsar site under the Ramsar Convention in 2000."
            });
    }
}
```

onePlace.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sunamganj.ViewModels
{
    public class onePlace
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<places> Items { get; set; }

        public onePlace()
        {
            Items = new List<places>();
        }
    }
}
```

places.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sunamganj.ViewModels
{
    public class places
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string shortDescription { get; set; }
        public string FullDescription { get; set; }
        public string itemImage { get; set; }
        public List<string>Gallery { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I want to add item into Gallery from placestovisit class. For that what to do?

Actually I want to add one photo gallery for each object. But I am not so much good in OOP. At this moment can I go with this concept or need to change the concept. If I can go with this one then how can I add item into Gallery from placestovisit class?

Answer (score 4):

`Gallery` is just a property of  your `places` class, and you can add items by accessing that property via an instance of `places` class.

One thing you should remember that the properties of reference types are *null* by default, so you need to initialize them.You can do that in your constructor:

```
public class places
{
    public places()
    {
        Gallery  = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Then you can add new items to your list like:

```
var plc = new places() { /* set the properties */ }

plc.Gallery.Add("new gallery");
```